# deallocating shared memory segment

Tags: linux, memory-management, ipc, shared-memory

I have code tht does

```
 int shmId = shmget(key, shmBytes, IPC_CREAT | 0666 );
 shmAddress = (char *) shmat(shmId, NULL, 0);
 /* do some stuff */
 /* detach */
 shmdt(shmAddress);
```

My question is,  do I ever need to de-allocate the segment I got with shmget?   or does shmdt take care of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you're using SYSV shared memory on Linux? Consider using the POSIX shared memory system (`shm_open`) instead. It's also more explicit about deletion (`shm_unlink`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Linux, you should consider using the [POSIX shared memory system](http://linux.die.net/man/7/shm_overview) (`shm_open`, `shm_unlink`), which mostly uses the standard POSIX file API (`mmap`, `ftruncate`, etc.) to interact with shared memory regions. It's also noted as being more modern as the old SYSV interface that you're using.

Anyway, the way to destroy SYSV segments is to use `shmctl(shmId, IPC_RMID, NULL)` before detaching the segment. From [`man 2 shmctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmctl):

> **IPC_RMID**
>
> Mark the segment to be destroyed. The segment will only actually be destroyed after the last process detaches it (i.e., when the shm_nattch member of the associated structure shmid_ds is zero). The caller must be the owner or creator, or be privileged. If a segment has been marked for destruction, then the (nonstandard) SHM_DEST flag of the shm_perm.mode field in the associated data structure retrieved by IPC_STAT will be set.
> The caller must ensure that a segment is eventually destroyed; otherwise its pages that were faulted in will remain in memory or swap.